# How to stop a paint event from propagating?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two widgets, `A` and `B`, `A` has `B` as its parent.

Inside the `A` widget, I have a timer to trigger the repaint slot of itself. Thus, the `paintEvent` of widget A is triggered. However, I found `B`'s `paintEvent` is also triggered. How could I trigger only `A`'s paintevet?

I have tried to accept `A`'s `paintEvent` as:

```
void A::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    paintA();
    event->accept();
}
```

But it doesn't help. What should I do?

Comment: How do you call the `A::paintEvent()`?

Comment: I connect a timer to A's repaint slot

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to stop the parent's paint event?

Comment: The parent is painting a map. Which could be slow...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [graphics view framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html)?

Comment: You can check [this question](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39556-update-of-the-child-widget-causes-paintEvent%28%29-of-the-parent-widget-to-be-called) from Qt centre. Seems related.

Comment: Do they have to have parent-child relationship?

Comment: @Nyaruko, who calls `B::paintEvent()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because Qt must do composition of the widgets.

Options:

- Consider making the widget a non-child and display it as a separate "window". You can use `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to make it look as a child widget. This option will give you perfect results as it leaves the composition to the underlying OS, which, at least on Desktop, will not repaint the bottom widget unless requested.
- Consider caching. Use `QPixmapCache` to cache all drawing of your bottom widget to one window-sized pixmap, which will be very fast to draw when needed.

Answer (score 2):

When a widget is sent a paint event, so are all of its enabled children. You can work around this by installing an event filter on the child widget and discarding any paint events you don't want.